# How to infer the generic return type that is bound to a generic parameter of a parameterized class in a typescript method?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following superclass, T is supposed to be the type the API returns

```
export class Command<T> {

}
```

This is a login command that extends the command:

```
export class LoginCommand extends Command<LoginResult> {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
```

And the return object:

```
export class LoginResult {
    success: boolean;
    token: string;
}
```

When calling the method:

```
public call<R>(command: model.command.Command<R>): R {
    return null as R; // code omitted
}
```

with the following parameter:

```
const cmd = new LoginCommand();
const success = this.call(cmd).success;
```

it yields an error :**[ts] Property 'success' does not exist on type '{}'**

**Question 1**: How to modify the method signature to correctly infer the R from Command as the return type? I've also tried the following syntax with the same result:

```
    public call<T extends Command<R>, R>(command: T): R
```

**Question 2**: Why is the ask method accepting parameters that do not extend Command? Passing in a string yields no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last question is the easiest to answer, your `Command` base class has no properties or methods so any type will be structurally equivalent to it including a string.

The other part of the problem is more difficult, if you pass a derived type from a generic type the compiler will not drill down to infer generic parameters.

You could do one of the following:

**Add a `with` operation to the `Command` class**

```
export class Command<T> {
    private something: "";
    with(fn: (cmd: Command<T>) => T) : T{
        return fn(this);
    }
}

//Usage:
public call<R>(command: Command<R>): R {
    return null as R; // code omitted
}

public doStuff() {
    const cmd = new LoginCommand();
    const success = cmd.with(this.call).success; // Works
}
```

**Add a simple casting method to the base class**

```
export class Command<T> {
    private something: "";
    asCmd(): Command<T> { return this;}
}

public doStuff() {
    const cmd = new LoginCommand();
    const success = this.call(cmd.asCmd()).success;
}
```